# python : object.__dict__ not showing all attributes

Tags: python, json, django, pretty-print

I am trying to print all the attibutes of an object. The purpose is mainly for debugging.

I am using the following code:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(object.__dict__), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

It prints the attibutes of the object.

But i was checking the list of all properties of the object using

```
dir(object)
```

I found that `__dict__` does not show some properties at all which are listed by `dir()`.

I thought of using dir(object) but it only a list of properties without attributes.

So i think:

```
`__dict__` has `incomplete` properties but with attirbutes

`dir()` has complete list of properties but no attibutes
```

So what is the best way to get a full dictionary of a attibutes of an object so that i can pretty print and see using `json.dumps`

**EXAMPLE**

I am working in a django project. And this is with related to db connection

so the example is of a variable names `db_con` which is of the following object

```
<django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f29dee47a58>
```

`__dict__` way

```
import json
print(json.dumps(db_con.__dict__), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

The output is

```
{
    "_thread_ident": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "_thread_sharing_count": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "_thread_sharing_lock": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "alias": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "autocommit": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "client": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "close_at": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "closed_in_transaction": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "commit_on_exit": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "connection": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "creation": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "errors_occurred": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "execute_wrappers": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "features": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "force_debug_cursor": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "in_atomic_block": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "introspection": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "isolation_level": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "needs_rollback": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "ops": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "queries_log": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "run_commit_hooks_on_set_autocommit_on": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "run_on_commit": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "savepoint_ids": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "savepoint_state": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "settings_dict": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "AUTOCOMMIT": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "CONN_MAX_AGE": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "ENGINE": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "HOST": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "NAME": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "OPTIONS": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "PASSWORD": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "PORT": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "TEST": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
            "CHARSET": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
            "COLLATION": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
            "MIRROR": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
            "NAME": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        },
        "TIME_ZONE": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
        "USER": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    },
    "timezone": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "timezone_name": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "validation": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
    "wrap_database_errors": ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
```

And the attibutes using dir()

```
print(json.dumps(dir(db_con), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
[
    "Database",
    "SchemaEditorClass",
    "__class__",
    "__delattr__",
    "__dict__",
    "__dir__",
    "__doc__",
    "__eq__",
    "__format__",
    "__ge__",
    "__getattribute__",
    "__gt__",
    "__hash__",
    "__init__",
    "__init_subclass__",
    "__le__",
    "__lt__",
    "__module__",
    "__ne__",
    "__new__",
    "__reduce__",
    "__reduce_ex__",
    "__repr__",
    "__setattr__",
    "__sizeof__",
    "__str__",
    "__subclasshook__",
    "__weakref__",
    "_close",
    "_commit",
    "_cursor",
    "_named_cursor_idx",
    "_nodb_connection",
    "_prepare_cursor",
    "_rollback",
    "_savepoint",
    "_savepoint_allowed",
    "_savepoint_commit",
    "_savepoint_rollback",
    "_set_autocommit",
    "_thread_ident",
    "_thread_sharing_count",
    "_thread_sharing_lock",
    "alias",
    "allow_thread_sharing",
    "autocommit",
    "check_constraints",
    "check_settings",
    "chunked_cursor",
    "clean_savepoints",
    "client",
    "client_class",
    "close",
    "close_at",
    "close_if_unusable_or_obsolete",
    "closed_in_transaction",
    "commit",
    "commit_on_exit",
    "connect",
    "connection",
    "constraint_checks_disabled",
    "copy",
    "create_cursor",
    "creation",
    "creation_class",
    "cursor",
    "data_type_check_constraints",
    "data_types",
    "data_types_suffix",
    "dec_thread_sharing",
    "disable_constraint_checking",
    "display_name",
    "enable_constraint_checking",
    "ensure_connection",
    "ensure_timezone",
    "errors_occurred",
    "execute_wrapper",
    "execute_wrappers",
    "features",
    "features_class",
    "force_debug_cursor",
    "get_autocommit",
    "get_connection_params",
    "get_new_connection",
    "get_rollback",
    "in_atomic_block",
    "inc_thread_sharing",
    "init_connection_state",
    "introspection",
    "introspection_class",
    "is_usable",
    "isolation_level",
    "make_cursor",
    "make_debug_cursor",
    "needs_rollback",
    "on_commit",
    "operators",
    "ops",
    "ops_class",
    "pattern_esc",
    "pattern_ops",
    "pg_version",
    "prepare_database",
    "queries",
    "queries_limit",
    "queries_log",
    "queries_logged",
    "rollback",
    "run_and_clear_commit_hooks",
    "run_commit_hooks_on_set_autocommit_on",
    "run_on_commit",
    "savepoint",
    "savepoint_commit",
    "savepoint_ids",
    "savepoint_rollback",
    "savepoint_state",
    "schema_editor",
    "set_autocommit",
    "set_rollback",
    "settings_dict",
    "temporary_connection",
    "timezone",
    "timezone_name",
    "validate_no_atomic_block",
    "validate_no_broken_transaction",
    "validate_thread_sharing",
    "validation",
    "validation_class",
    "vendor",
    "wrap_database_errors"
]
```

I want to use `db_con['queries']` to get a the list of queries but its not shown in `__dict__` and can be confusing if dont know `db_con['queries']` exists which i came to know through `dir()`

**Thirdparty Solution i found:**

I am using runserver_plus

```
python manage.py runserver_plus
```

> Runserver_plus: Django-extensions includes a management command
>   (runserver_plus) to start the Werkzeug interactive debugger with your
>   project
>
> Werkzeug: Werkzeug is a WSGI utility library for Python. Beyond
>   others, it includes an interactive debugger - what this means is that
>   when your python application throws an exception, Werkzeug will
>   display the exception stacktrace in the browser (that’s not a big
>   deal) and allow you to write python commands interactively wherever
>   you want in that stacktrace (that’s the important stuff).

whereever i want to check a variable i add `a=+1` after that so that it throws an exception `(UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment)` then i can open an interactive console there and check the object attibutes using  `dump(var)` which shows all the attributes. Currently i check the attributes using that.

I want to do it using regular python way.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.__dict__` is the storage for instance attributes (for dict-based classes - some are slot-based and some (C coded) are just, well, what they are xD). Other "properties" (caveat: in Python, 'property' is also the name of a builtin class that provides generic support for computed attributes) that you'll find using `dir(obj)` belong either to the class or one of it's parent, so they are obviously not in `obj.__dict__`.

Also and FWIW, `dir()` doesn't necessarily lists **all** of an object's properties :

> Help on built-in function dir in module **builtin**:
>
> dir(...)
>       dir([object]) -> list of strings
>
> ```
> If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
> Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
> of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
> If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
> the default dir() logic is used and returns:
>   for a module object: the module's attributes.
>   for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
>     of its bases.
>   for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
>     recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
> ```

If you really want to retrieve all properties *values*, you can use `[getattr][1](obj, name[, default])` ie:

```
everything = {k: getattr(obj, k) for k in dir(obj)}
```

**BUT** you won't be able to serialize this to json - functions / methods, properties (the Python builtin type...), classes (the object's class) and quite a few other things are not json-serializable (how would you serialize a function ?)

Also, you may have classes implementing `__getattr__` (usually for dynamic delegation), so even with `dir` there might be properties (in the generic meaning) that are accessible on your object but that just can't be listed via inspection.

> So what is the best way to get a full dictionary of a attibutes of an object so that i can pretty print

Something like `inspect.getmembers(obj)` comes to mind. But you may find out that `obj.__dict__` is usually the most useful part already.

> and see using json.dumps

Well, cf above...

> I want to use db_con['queries'] to get a the list of queries but its not shown in **dict** and can be confusing if dont know db_con['queries'] exists which i came to know through dir()

if you're in the python shell, [you can just use the builtin help system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help).

Comment: i tried `{k: getattr(obj, k) for k in dir(obj)}` it says obj undefined. How to pass obj to getattr(obj, k)